# Year range picker , есть библиотека или как реализовать?

Tags: android

[image: range picker]
Как реализовать такой пикер, выбор нужен только по годам. Дело в том что нужен такой же дизайн и вряд ли найду что нибудь готовое и легкое в кастомизации.  Можете подсказать шаги реализации такого пикера?

Comment: По идее можно просто взять диалог и в него поместить кастомную разметку с 2-мя `NumberPicker` с заданными интервалами чисел.

Comment: а получится контролировать ситуацию когда на левом пикере выбран 2000 год, чтобы на правом ниже 2000 уже нельзя было выбрать? И еще: дизайн NumberPicker в другой версии андроид может быть изменен, возможно ли его вью самому задавать, чтобы не зависеть от изменения в дизайне?

Comment: Да, получится. Просто кодом - вешайте слушатель выбора на левый и в зависимости от значения оного устанавливайте набор значений для правого. Из коробки такого, конечно, не будет, надо вручную прописать. Со стандартными компонентами да, есть проблема с внешним видом на разных версиях. Если этого надо избежать - придётся вручную виджет делать. Или либу стороннюю брать или выдёргивать нужные стили и чрез них пробовать. Или свою вьюху писать. Тут уж от требований всё зависит.

Comment: на скриншоте стандартный диалог с двумя стандартными NumberPicker. насчет дизайна - если для диалога (или всего приложения) вы укажите конкретную тему и стили, то он будет в одном дизайне более менее

Comment: Дизайн этого пикера разве на всех версиях андроид одинаковый?  Я просто не знаю,  если стандартный пикер позволяет стилями менять цвет текса,  разделителей,  фона, то можно и стандартный стилизовать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри стандарнтые пикеры https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.
В крайнем случае возьми стандартный cardview и засунь в него 2 listview

Comment: У ListView надо будет логику докручивания до ближайшей вью дописывать